# program terminates if char size 30 or greater is taken in struct

Tags: arrays, c, struct

HEADER FILE- if I change char size from 30 to 20 or less code works fine but if its 30 or above  it does not execute after for loop of 5th case in main code.

```
struct Data
{
    int Emp_id;
    char Emp_name[30];
    char Emp_city[30];
};

void input(struct Data emp[], int n)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("enter employee id of %d employee: \n", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", &emp[i].Emp_id);

        fflush(stdin);
        printf("enter employee name of %d employee: \n", i + 1);
        gets(emp[i].Emp_name);

        fflush(stdin);
        printf("enter employee city of %d employee: \n", i + 1);
        gets(emp[i].Emp_city);
    }
}
```

MAIN CODE- add function is executed in 5th case where the loop stops if character size is 30 or more in struct of header file. The code also works if I make one iteration less making for loop like this - for(int i=n-5;i<n-1;i++)but including last iteration terminates program and display function does not execute.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "data.h"

void find(struct Data emp[], int n);
void sortid(struct Data emp[], int n);
void sortAlp(struct Data emp[], int n);
void count(struct Data emp[], int n);
void add(struct Data emp[], int n);
void display(struct Data emp[], int n);

int main(void)
{
    int n;
    int a;

    printf("enter the number of employees:\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    struct Data emp[n];

    input(emp, n);

    printf("enter the operation you want to perform:\n");
    printf("1 - to find employee record from employee id\n");
    printf("2 - to sort employee record on basis of employee id\n");
    printf("3 - to alphabetically sort array of characters\n");
    printf("4 - to count the number of employees in database\n");
    printf("5 - to add 5 more records\n");

    scanf("%d", &a);

    switch (a)
    {
    case 1:

        find(emp, n);

        break;

    case 2:
        sortid(emp, n);
        display(emp, n);
        break;

    case 3:
        sortAlp(emp, n);
        display(emp, n);
        break;

    case 4:
        count(emp, n);

        break;

    case 5:
        add(emp, n);

        break;
    }

    return 0;
}

void find(struct Data emp[], int n)
{
    int a;
    int count = 0;

    printf("Enter the employee id: ");
    scanf("%d", &a);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (a == emp[i].Emp_id)
        {
            printf("Employee id: %d\n", emp[i].Emp_id);
            printf("Employee name: %s\n", emp[i].Emp_name);
            printf("Employee city: %s\n", emp[i].Emp_city);
            count++;
        }
    }
    if (count == 0)
    {
        printf("Employee id does not exist");
    }
}

void sortid(struct Data emp[], int n)
{
    int temp;
    char temp2[30];
    char temp3[30];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (emp[i].Emp_id > emp[j].Emp_id)
            {

                temp = emp[i].Emp_id;
                emp[i].Emp_id = emp[j].Emp_id;
                emp[j].Emp_id = temp;

                strcpy(temp2, emp[i].Emp_name);
                strcpy(emp[i].Emp_name, emp[j].Emp_name);
                strcpy(emp[j].Emp_name, temp2);

                strcpy(temp3, emp[i].Emp_city);
                strcpy(emp[i].Emp_city, emp[j].Emp_city);
                strcpy(emp[j].Emp_city, temp3);
            }
        }
    }
}

void sortAlp(struct Data emp[], int n)
{
    int temp2;
    char temp[30];
    char temp3[30];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (emp[i].Emp_name[0] > emp[j].Emp_name[0])
            {
                strcpy(temp, emp[i].Emp_name);
                strcpy(emp[i].Emp_name, emp[j].Emp_name);
                strcpy(emp[j].Emp_name, temp);

                temp2 = emp[i].Emp_id;
                emp[i].Emp_id = emp[j].Emp_id;
                emp[j].Emp_id = temp2;

                strcpy(temp3, emp[i].Emp_city);
                strcpy(emp[i].Emp_city, emp[j].Emp_city);
                strcpy(emp[j].Emp_city, temp3);
            }
        }
    }
}

void count(struct Data emp[], int n)
{
    int k;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        k = i;
    }

    printf("number of employees: %d\n", k + 1);
}

void add(struct Data emp[], int n)
{
    n = n + 5;

    for (int i = n - 5; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("enter employee id of %d employee: \n", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", &emp[i].Emp_id);

        fflush(stdin);
        printf("enter employee name of %d employee: \n", i + 1);
        gets(emp[i].Emp_name);

        fflush(stdin);
        printf("enter employee city of %d employee: \n", i + 1);
        gets(emp[i].Emp_city);
    }
    //Program stops here without executing display
    display(emp, n);
}

void display(struct Data emp[], int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("employee id of %d employee: %d \n", (i + 1), emp[i].Emp_id);

        printf("employee name of %d employee: %s \n", (i + 1), emp[i].Emp_name);

        printf("employee city of %d employee: %s \n", (i + 1), emp[i].Emp_city);
    }
}
```

Comment: `gets` has been removed from the C standard library, so you should stop using it (and replace it with a safer alternative)

Comment: You're writing outside the `emp` array. You allocate `n` elements in `main()`, then in `add()` you write to elements `n` through `n+4`.

Comment: Instead of `gets(emp[i].Emp_name);` you could do `fgets(emp[i].Emp_name, sizeof emp[i].Emp_name, stdin);` which would not allow for writing out of bounds.

Comment: And never use `fflush(stdin)` - it's implementation defined behaviour (at best) and most likely undefined behaviour.

Comment: This is an awful lot of code for something that's likely only requires 20% of this code. Please [edit] your question with a [mre]

Comment: You should not put any function definitions in a header unless there really is a good reason. In your case, there isn't.

Comment: Regarding your title: "char size 30 or greater" is rather ambigous. Many people will read it as "character holding a value >= 30". What you mean is a "char **array** of size 30 or greater".

Comment: SWAPNIL SRIVASTAVA --> What is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dependency on array size is a coincidence, buffer overrun always happen in the 5th case.

In your program, you read `n`, then you allocate an array of `n` entries. Later changes of `n`, if any (there are none actually, the operation in `add` changes a copy) don’t change array size. This way, `add` writes data past the array, which is forbidden and may crash the program, or worse.

What you need is dynamic memory allocation, like:

```c
// create an array of n entries
struct Data *emp = malloc(n * sizeof(struct Data));

// grow it (or shrink) to new_n entries
emp = realloc(emp, new_n * sizeof(struct Data));
n = new_n;

// destroy it
free(emp);
emp = NULL; // safeguard, should be right after free
```

Note that when growing the array, you need to change the actual `emp` and `n` you use in the code, while functions only get copies (copy of the pointer in the case of `emp`, not of the whole array). So either do that in `main` right before calling `add`, or change it to accept pointers to these variables to let it do that work itself.

Comment: Thanks , using dynamic memory solved the problem. This was my first question on stack and the code wasn't that proper so sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Note that in theory, you should check malloc and especially realloc return value (see the (docs)[https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html]). In practice that’s unreliable (try malloc in a loop on a Linux system) and often pointless (what can the program do if malloc indeed fails?)

Answer (score 0):

```
printf("enter the number of employees:\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    struct Data emp[n];
```

You have a problem here: you can not just read n and then declare an array of `emp[n]` elements. You are reading it at *runtime*, but the compiler needs to know how many `emp` to allocated space for. The compiler need the info at compile time. It can not wait until the `scanf()` is run.

You must use a constant value, or use dynamic allocation, like in `//1 //2` and `//3` below

```
    #define   EMP_SIZE 42
    struct Data emp1[EMP_SIZE];  // 1

    struct Data emp2[42];  // 2

    n = n + 5; // 3
    struct Data* emp3 = (struct Data*) malloc(n*sizeof(struct Data));
```

For the same reason

```
void add(struct Data emp[], int n)
{
    n = n + 5;

    for (int i = n - 5; i < n; i++)
    {}
```

also does not work. I believe you supposing that setting `n = n + 5;` will by some way extend the array and allocate 5 new `emp`. It will not. It will just set `n`, an `int`, to `n + 5`. And in the `for` you are trying to write over these new `emp` records.

Well, there no new records and your program will crash soon afterwards.

### more about your code

You may be by now sort of tired of writing `struct Data` all over the place. In general people use to write

```
typedef struct
{
    int  Emp_id;
    char Emp_name[30];
    char Emp_city[30];

}   Data;
```

This command defines `Data` as an anonymous `struct`. It does not create one, just defines a name for it, for the whole set.

And you can the write

```
void input(Data emp[], int n);
```

instead of

```
void input(struct Data emp[], int n);
```

#### The use of headers

In general the `.h` files contains the definitions and prototypes. The idea is to create code in sets of 2 files. The header has the declarations and prototypes. a `.c` file has the code for the functions.

And a 3rd file hosts `main()`. Why? Because writing this way you have have many `.c` files implementing `main()` and testing different functions of your program.

And when the functions are ok you keep (or sell) the compiled code from the functions, and the `.h` with the declarations, so others can use it in their programs, just by including the headers and pointing the linker to the functions code, in compiled form. This *compiled form* is called a `library`. This is the very same case of using `printf()` by including `stdio.h`. `libc` is the library and `stdlib.h` are the header in Unix.

#### writing around the data

```
void find(struct Data emp[], int n);
void sortid(struct Data emp[], int n);
void sortAlp(struct Data emp[], int n);
void count(struct Data emp[], int n);
void add(struct Data emp[], int n);
void display(struct Data emp[], int n);
```

zooming out of your the code, all functions deal with an array of `struct Data`, and `n` is the array size. It is called a *container* and is the most common structure after the simple `array` itself.

So you can write

```
typedef struct
{
    int     id;
    char    name[20];
    char    city[20];

}   Employee;

typedef struct
{
    unsigned    N;
    unsigned    capacity;
    Employee*   E;

}   Data;
```

Here `Data` is a container of `Employee`. But inside `Data` is the `N` size component and it is really handy. This is called encapsulation in OOP literature.

#### An example, refactoring your code

I will rearrange your code and reimplement a few of the functions, so you cam compare the two ways. There are many many other ways of writing this, and I am not even saying that this one is good or yours is bad.

#### a revised header

```
// f1-data.h
typedef struct
{
    int     id;
    char    name[20];
    char    city[20];

}   Employee;

typedef struct
{
    unsigned    N;
    unsigned    capacity;
    Employee*   E;

}   Data;

Data*       create_Data(unsigned);
Data*       delete_Data(Data*);

int         add(Employee*, Data*);
int         add5(Data*);
int         count(Data*);
void        display(Data*,const char*);
Employee*   find(int,Data*);
Employee*   input();

//void        sortid(Data*);
//void        sortAlp(Data*);
// f1-data.h end
```

About the changes:

- `Data` is now a set of `Employee`. From your code it seems that the size must be dynamic, so `Data` has a field `capacity` that holds the present capacity, and a field `N` with the present size. `E` is an array of Employee. A short name helps, because it is used many many times. I will write `add5()` as an example of the common way of extending the structure
- `create_data()` returns a pointer to a dataset with the asked capacity
- `delete_data()` returns `NULL`. The purpose is to give a simple way to invalidate the pointer after deleting a set.
- `find()` returns a pointer to an `Employee` with the given `id`, or `NULL`. It is more practical this way, instead of a function that writes to the screen every call.
- `add5()` is implemented as an example of how to expand the array
- `input()` returns a pointer to an `Employee`, so we can test the program with data and NO interactivity at all.
- there is no need for `'Emp'` prefix in the fields inside the struct. We can imagine that fields inside `Employee` `struct` are `Employee` data.
- `_id` was changed to `id`. It is recommended that no program use one or more underlines at the start of names. These are somewhat reserved to library implementors.
- `display()` now has a title string, because it is useful in examples.
- the code for the functions in a file `.c` named as the `h.`, the usual way. I will all 3 in sequence to make it easier to cut and paste for the site case you want to test it.

#### main() for the test

```
int main(void)
{
    Data* set1 = create_Data(4);
    display(set1, "empty. (just testing)");
    add5(set1);
    display(set1, "empty. (added 5 in cap.)");
    // now inserts until error
    printf("inserting employees until error\n");
    Employee* e = NULL;
    while (set1->N < set1->capacity)
    {   e = input();
        add(e, set1);
        free(e);
    }
    display(set1, "Now set should be full");
    set1 = delete_Data(set1);
}
```

The logic:

- A set is created with a 4 `Employee` capacity
- `display()` is called
- The set is expanded to 5 more records and displayed
- calling `input()` is called and records are inserted until error
- `display()` is called to show the now full set
- the set is deleted.

#### test output

```
empty. (just testing)
0 Employees [Cap. 4]


empty. (added 5 in cap.)
0 Employees [Cap. 9]


inserting employees until error
Now set should be full
9 Employees [Cap. 9]

  1         420         Jhonny 420 Jr [ City  420 ]
  2         421         Jhonny 421 Jr [ City  421 ]
  3         422         Jhonny 422 Jr [ City  422 ]
  4         423         Jhonny 423 Jr [ City  423 ]
  5         424         Jhonny 424 Jr [ City  424 ]
  6         425         Jhonny 425 Jr [ City  425 ]
  7         426         Jhonny 426 Jr [ City  426 ]
  8         427         Jhonny 427 Jr [ City  427 ]
  9         428         Jhonny 428 Jr [ City  428 ]
```

#### complete code (3 files)

```
// f1-data.h
typedef struct
{
    int     id;
    char    name[20];
    char    city[20];

}   Employee;

typedef struct
{
    unsigned    N;
    unsigned    capacity;
    Employee*   E;

}   Data;

Data*       create_Data(unsigned);
Data*       delete_Data(Data*);

int         add(Employee*, Data*);
int         add5(Data*);
int         count(Data*);
void        display(Data*,const char*);
Employee*   find(int,Data*);
Employee*   input();

//void        sortid(Data*);
//void        sortAlp(Data*);
// f1-data.h end


// f1-data.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "f1-data.h"

int add(Employee* E, Data* S)
{
    // add Employee E
    if (S->N == S->capacity) return -1;  // full
    // space we have: copy Employee
    S->E[S->N] = *E;
    S->N += 1;  // count one
    return S->N;
}

int add5(Data* Set)
{   // adds 5 records to Set
    if (Set == NULL) return -1;
    int   n_size = 5 + Set->capacity;
    Employee* temp   = (Employee*)realloc(Set->E, n_size * sizeof(Employee));
    if (temp == NULL) return -2; // could not extend?
    Set->E = temp; // that is all
    Set->capacity = n_size;
    return 0;
}

int         count(Data* S){ return S->N; }

Data*       create_Data(unsigned cap)
{ 
    Data* set = (Data*)malloc(cap * sizeof(Data));
    set->N    = 0; // empty
    set->capacity = cap;
    set->E    = (Employee*)malloc(cap * sizeof(Employee));
    return set;
}

Data*       delete_Data(Data* set)
{
    if (set == NULL) return NULL;
    free(set->E); // frees Employees first
    free(set);    
    return NULL;
}

void        display(Data* Set, const char* msg)
{
    if (msg != NULL) printf("%s\n", msg);
    printf("%d Employees [Cap. %u]\n\n", Set->N, Set->capacity);
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < Set->N; i++)
        printf("\
%3u    %8d  %20s [ %s ]\n",
            i + 1,
            Set->E[i].id,
            Set->E[i].name,
            Set->E[i].city
            );
    printf("\n");
}

Employee*   find(int id, Data* S)
{
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < S->N; i++)
        if (id == S->E[i].id)
        {   // found
            Employee* found = (Employee*)malloc(sizeof(Employee));
            *found          = S->E[i];
            return found;
        }
    return NULL;
}

Employee*   input()
{  // returns a new Employee record
    static int id    = 420;
    Employee*  new_E = (Employee*)malloc(sizeof(Employee));
    new_E->id        = id;
    sprintf(new_E->name, "Jhonny%4d Jr", id);
    sprintf(new_E->city, "City %4d", id);
    id += 1;
    return new_E;
}

//void        sortid(Data* Set){};
//void        sortAlp(Data* Set){};
// f1-data.c end

// f1.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "f1-data.h"

int main(void)
{
    Data* set1 = create_Data(4);
    display(set1, "empty. (just testing)");
    add5(set1);
    display(set1, "empty. (added 5 in cap.)");
    // now inserts until error
    printf("inserting employees until error\n");
    Employee* e = NULL;
    while (set1->N < set1->capacity)
    {   e = input();
        add(e, set1);
        free(e);
    }
    display(set1, "Now set should be full");
    set1 = delete_Data(set1);
}
//f1.c end
```

#### about the sort

Note that the sort functions just changes the field of sorting, so you should pass the compare function only, and write a single sort. Or maybe just call **`qsort()`**

**Note for reviewers**: I always cast the pointer returned from `malloc()`, and I know that some 90's text like the C-FAQ writes against it. No need to point me this.

Comment: And a note for you: unlike C++, C does allow the array length to be determined at runtime. That’s called VLA, Variable-Length Array.

Comment: I know that. But it is a thing for students. Never saw it in production code. As a former COBOL programmer I still remember using the DEPENDING ON clause, for the same effect. Yes, in uppercase.  But  in C it makes the stack size a mystery for the whole program life.